# When something finishes in future I will let you know (inform you)

Tags: sentence-construction

I'm not sure how to structure my sentence in a correct manner.

What I want to express is that I've started something, and will let someone know once it (has?) finish.

Here is an example:

> I will be monitoring the progress and I will let you know once it is
> finished.

So I will be watching/monitoring the progress (I will have a look from time to time to see if its finished) and when I see/acknowledge the process is complete I will let you know.

Comment: Yes, that's fine - or _when it is finished_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds natural. I think I would usually say *monitoring progress* without the *the* but I think that is just a matter of personal style and *the* is fine there too. As @KateBunting mentioned in a comment *when it is finished* is an equally correct alternative.